# How can I add relative paths to libraries in perl?

Tags: perl, declaration, relative-path

I want to have a library (my_library_1) which makes use of another library in a folder relative to itself. If I write it like this:

```
use lib "/./libraries/";
use my_library_2;
```

It will use the path from where I execute the script.

If I use the following as proposed in other similar quiestions:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/./libraries/";
use my_library_2;
```

It will be relative to the main script being executed, therefore if I'm calling this library from another script, and then this library calles the other one (my_library_1), the library declaration will not be as expected if the first library (my_library_1) and the main script are in the same folder.

How can I solve this issue without relying on absolute paths?

Edit: To add some more information
This is the current structure:

```
folder
\_folder_1
 \__main_script
\_folder_2
 \__my_library_1
 \__folder_1
   \___my_library_2
```

I want to reference library_3 from library_2 with a relative path. The two proposed options do not work when I use them on "my_library_2".

Comment: [`Module::Path`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Path)?

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand the situation, but if a script uses a package, then that package needs to load some other package from the same module, then hasn’t the script already made sure the whole module is in `@INC` and it should Just Work™?

Comment: @Biffen I just added some more information. When I load "my_library_1 from the main_script it will complain cause it says that is not able to find my_library_2, but if I move the main_script to the same folder as "my_library_1" it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative) is a straightforward way to use `__FILE__` to add absolutized lib paths relative to either a script or module. It also documents the equivalent core module commands so it doesn't need to be installed.

In the script:

```
use lib::relative '../folder2';
```

or:

```
use Cwd ();
use File::Basename ();
use File::Spec ();
use lib File::Spec->catdir(File::Basename::dirname(Cwd::abs_path __FILE__), '../folder2');
```

Similarly in the module:

```
use lib::relative 'folder1';
```

I recommend the much simpler `__FILE__` approach over FindBin in all cases - FindBin is action at a distance, requires workarounds, and has serious bugs on old Perls that cannot be fixed because [it isn't available on CPAN](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=123752).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `__FILE__` to get the directory name of `my_library_1.pm`:

**folder1/main.pl**:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;

use lib "$FindBin::RealBin/../folder2/";
use my_library_1;
```

**folder2/my_library_1.pm**:

```
package my_library_1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename qw(dirname);

my $dir;
BEGIN {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
}
use lib "$dir/folder1";
use my_library_2;
```